# Regex String retrieval

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string where I need to extract the ID from the very end of the string (IgnoreCase is true):

String:

```
[Test].Test Stuff].[Class].&[002 - My Hat]&[002-01 - Big Hat]
```

What I want to extract:

```
002-01
```

So far, what I have is this:

```
(?<=&\[).+(?=\s\-\s.+\])
```

But I am getting this:

```
002 - My Hat]&[002-01
```

Comment: Some more string examples would help.

Comment: What is the criteria for your string? Do your target string follow some expected structure?

Comment: Each string I get will have this structure. The only things that change is instead of "My Hat", it can change to "My Coat"

Comment: So "My Hat]" is the end of the string--always? There will be no trailing spaces or other irrelevant characters?

Comment: Simply this: `(\d{3}-\d{2})` matches what you want in your example string. Is that not enough? Just pull the group from that result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an end-of-input anchor `$` at the end, and prohibit matching of `[]` as part of your non-empty `.+` sequences, like this:

```
(?<=&\[)([^\[\]]+)(?=\s\-\s[^\[\]]+\]$)
//       ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^   ^
//          |                 |      |
//        No square brackets here    |
//                                   |
//                        End of input marker here
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How can you make your code as beautiful like that? Do you use any tools or something?

Comment: @SonerGönül If you mean the formatting, I simply type while looking at the SO's preview, and add spaces until the characters line up.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version:

`(?<=\]\&\[)(\d+-\d+)`

Explanation:

`?<=` does a [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This means that it will match the characters inside the () braces, but not return them. The characters inside this Positive Lookbehind that I've used are `]&[`

Then it matches `\d+` which means 1 to infinity consecutive digits, followed by a hyphen `-` and again a `\d+`

Also, http://regex101.com/r/iW4cP1 for playing around with the same.

Comment: You really should explain *why* this works.

Comment: @NathanielFord Added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

if the format of the string is always the same, make use of the last `]&[` in a regex like this:

```
\]&\[([\d-]*).*
```

that should do the trick if the numbers are always following the ]&[

otherwise i think something like this should do the trick:

```
\[([\d-]+)[^\[]*\]$
```

so the group of numbers that are followed by any non-[ characters all the way to the last ]

Comment: Your second option doesn't appear to match anything. Maybe you forgot the quantifier on "not an opening bracket"?

Comment: yep :-) was writing without testing the pattern... just to show the way

Comment: tested the second regex and it works

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is actually pretty close, if you add the ] bracket to it you should match what you want.

```
(?<=\]&\[).+(?=\s\-\s.+\])
```

If the number format is the same always you don't really need the lookahead, instead you can match the format.

```
(?<=\]&\[)\d{3}-\d{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is at the end of the string why not use that hint to inform the processor of that? Here is using the regex option of right to left:

```
string data = @"[Test].Test Stuff].[Class].&[002 - My Hat]&[002-01 - Big Hat]";

string pattern = @"(?:\[)(?<Data>\d+-\d+)";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(data, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups["Data"].Value); // 002-01
```